# Automated build file with tests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, setup.py

For one stage of the interview process I was asked to write a program and send it as "automated build file that compiles code and runs the tests'. I've completed program swiftly, but I was not sure how to develop such solution with tests and was not sure what is the best practice for that.

I could not find much information online, other than simple file building tutorials, I've created directories that look like that

```
├── MANIFEST.in
├── build
│   ├── bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64
│   └── lib
│       └── bank
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── bankapp.py
│           └── tests
│               ├── __init__.py
│               └── bankapp_test.py
├── bank
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bankapp.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── bankapp_test.py
├── setup.py
```

with setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "bankapp",
    version = "0.1",
    author = "M",
    author_email = "xxx",
    description = (""),
    packages=find_packages(),
    tests_require=['pytest'],
      test_suite="tests",                          
)
```

Then I am struggling to integrate the test into my package so it works as required in the instruction.
When I run it from terminal with pytest bankapp_test.py it works fine.
When I develop via python3 setup.py develop: I can then import bank.bankapp but not directly bankapp.. Also, I cannot import bank.tests.bankapp_test after developing, because in the code I have

```
sys.path.append("..")
import bankapp as b
```

which works fine with pytest, but not when accessing the module. I tried to just test it within main bankapp.py, at the bottom after all classes I've added

```
def tests():
    test_one()
    test_two()
    test_three()
    test_four()
    test_five()
    test_six()
    print( "Tests passed: 6/6")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
    print("loaded")
```

with from tests.bankapp_test import * that works from file directly (!), but not when I develop it and try to import. It gives me error at the import line.

I've read so many topics already, can you advice me what's the best practice for something like that and what would be the best solution here, not sure if I'm missing something or misunderstanding the setup.py build (I still dont understand for instance why it develops/installs as bankapp but can't import as such, only i have to use import bank.bankapp...)

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT:

btw python3 setup.py test does not work either and gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tests/lib_test.py", line 160, in test_sample_file
    with open(path) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tests/../sample.json5'
```

Comment: Can you use a makefile?

Comment: Check out [BuildBot](https://buildbot.net/).  Never used it but seems to be just what you are looking for